# Using pseudo selector :after to create an overlay over an image -- not taking the full height

Tags: css

Trying to create an overlay effect on hover, using :after, but it's not taking the full height.

It will work if I give a:after a fixed height in pixels. But I was hoping not to set a static height so it can be applied to images of all sizes.

Thanks in advance!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .4s;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
}

a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonballfanon/images/7/70/Random.png/revision/latest?cb=20161221030547">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%` from `a` and added `display: inline-block;` By default `a` tags have a display value of `inline` which ignores `width` and `height` values so they weren't doing anything before anyway. `display: inline-block;` is probably what you wanted to go with from the beginning.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
}

a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonballfanon/images/7/70/Random.png/revision/latest?cb=20161221030547">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tag default display is `display: inline`.

To achieve the desired result you should display your `<a>` as `inline-block`. See docs: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

```
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .4s;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
}

a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonballfanon/images/7/70/Random.png/revision/latest?cb=20161221030547">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a>` element is not getting the full height, because by default is displayed as `inline`.

You can set `display:inline-block`; to change the default render behavior... or you can play with the `position` property.

Setting the `container` to `position:relative`, and the `a` and the `a:after` to `position:absolute`, will let you force the `a:after` to adjust to `top:0px;` and `bottom:0px;` covering the full height.

With that changes, everything works as expected.

Check it.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
}

a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    transition: all .4s;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
    opacity:0.2;
}

a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonballfanon/images/7/70/Random.png/revision/latest?cb=20161221030547">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a display block:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
}
```